# How to set one condition display (ng-show) on the group of many <td> tags with AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

Having a column with many cells, I would like to set only one conditional display (ng-show), for all group of < td > tags concerned.

```
    @* //facturation *@
                            <facturation ng-show="vue=='Facturations'">
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{jalons.totalFacture}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{jalons.penaliteReserveApplicable}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{jalons.franchiAvecResereve.dateContratLeveeReserve}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{jalons.totalRegle}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{jalons.montantRestantFacture}}</p>
                                </td>
                            </facturation>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with help of ng-if-start="condition". At the same time, we can achieve a similar effect by enclosing the concerned < td> tags with the < tr> tag and setting the condition on it.

```
@*<tr ng-show="vue=='Facturations'">*@
                                <td ng-if-start="vue=='Facturations'">
                                    <p>{{jalons.totalFacture}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{jalons.penaliteReserveApplicable}}
</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>
{{jalons.franchiAvecResereve.dateContratLeveeReserve}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{jalons.totalRegle}}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td ng-if-end>
                    `enter code here`                <p>{{jalons.montantRestantFacture}}</p>
                                </td>
```